# Page Not Found 404 Django & Python

Tags: django

I am having the following error

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in Decoder.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
form.html [name='form1']
hl7 [name='hl7']
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

[image]

**Its my first time writing code using Django**

`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('', include('hl7rest.urls')),
]`

**and this other file**

```
from . import views
```

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [

```
path('form.html', views.render_form_View, name='form1'),
```

path('hl7', views.hl7_web_view ,name='hl7'),

]

Comment: None of your paths match with an empty string, hence requesting the `/` page makes no sense.

Comment: How can I repair the nonsense of the empty string?

Comment: well what view do you want to trigger if you visit  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ?

Comment: the file display_form.html

Comment: that is *not* a view, but a template. A view does not per se renders a template, nor does it have to render at most one. A view simply should return a HTTP response, and can make use of tooing to assist with that.

Answer (score 2):

Your paths don' t match the request.
You can create a TemplateView subclass for render your template:

**Views**

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "display_form.html"
```

**Url patterns**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```